# Proving $\mathbb{P}(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} S_n = \infty) = 1$ where $S_i \sim \exp(\lambda_i)$ and $\sup_n \lambda_n < \infty$.

Tags: probability, random-variables, exponential-distribution

I was working through J.R. Norris Markov Chains and got stuck at exercise 2.3.1. The question is the following:

> Let $S_1, S_2, \ldots$ be independent exponential random variables of parameters $\lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots$ respectively. Show that $\lambda_1 S_1$ is exponential with parameter $1$.
>
> Use the strong law of large numbers to show, first in the special case $\lambda_n = 1$ for all $n$, and then subject only to the condition $\sup_n \lambda_n < \infty$, that
>   $$
>  \mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} S_n = \infty\right) = 1
> $$
>   Is the condition $\sup_n \lambda_n < \infty$.

I was able to prove that $\lambda_i S_i \sim \exp(1)$, but I was not able to prove that $\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} S_n = \infty\right) = 1
$, even for the special case $\lambda_n = 1 \, \forall n$.

Intuitively I have concluded the following: Since $\mathbb{E}(S_n) = \frac{1}{\lambda_n}$ and $\sup_n \lambda_n < \infty$, we can conclude that
$$
\mathbb{E}(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} S_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{E}(S_n) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\lambda_n} = \infty,
$$
since $\sup_n \lambda_n < \infty$.

Is there any way to build on this intuition? How do I exactly use the strong law of large numbers to solve the exercise?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let $\lambda_n = 1$. Then, by the strong law of large numbers, $$\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^{N} S_n \to 1$$ almost surely. In particular, the sequence of partial sums $(\sum_{n=1}^{N} S_n)_{N\geq 1}$ is almost surely unbounded (otherwise the limit would be $0$ on a set of nonzero probability).

Now assume $\Lambda:=\sup_n \lambda_n < \infty$. By what we've just shown and because $\lambda_i S_i \sim \exp(1)$, we know that $$\mathbb{P}\left(\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_n S_n = \infty\right) = 1.$$

But if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_n S_n (\omega) = \infty$, then also $\frac{1}{\Lambda}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\lambda_n S_n (\omega) = \infty$, and

$$\infty = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\lambda_n}{\Lambda} S_n \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} S_n .$$